# Wood filler or glue for small fracture after nailing?

Tags: wood, adhesive, nails, wood-filler

I stupidly neglected to pre-drill a hole before nailing into a thin bit of wood, causing a small (hairline, inch each way) split.

I believe it needs only a cosmetic repair - and it would be hard to clamp, putting me off expanding glues.

The nail needs to stay in place, but not be glued in place.

Should I use filler, or glue?

Comment: It would help if you'd explain better what you're doing. The nature of the repair may depend on it. For example, I'd probably pull the nail, rub wood glue into the crack and let that dry, then drill for the nail, but I can't be sure with what you've told us.

Answer (score 1):

If the nail is holding this thin piece in place I would use wood glue over filler, filler may not hold the split together where wood glue would.

Comment: Sorry, I could have made that clearer, it's a nail into it, not securing it itself.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not enough concern to make it worth replacing, put a little filler in it.